# Ploblem facing in using javascript plugin in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, mathjax, mobile-development, wiris

I need to use/import a JavaScript plugin in React-native.
Plugin file contains functions, written in javascript and not in es6 format. I need to use those in react-native either by Webview or can be other way.

I already tried WebView, But html code is not even loading JS plugin file (`<script type="text/javascript" src="./testjs.js">`)
Because when I give it a wrong path It should give me some file missing error, While Simple alert on same place is working.
here below is render on RN screen :-

```
render () {
    var HTML = `<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="./testjs.js"></script> </head> <body> <div id="workbookControl"></div> <div id="tableeditor" style="font-size : 50px;">I am written inside source HTML</div> </body> </html>`
    var jsCode = ` true;`
    return (
        <WebView
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            source={{ html: HTML }}
            injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
            onMessage={() => {}}
            javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
        />
    )
}
```

And here is code of testjs.js

```
(function hello(ddd) { alert("heiii"); return "Hello"; })(); true;
```

I want to call this hello() from testjs.js, How can I do that ?

Comment: Please may you provide a [mcve]? Otherwise we’ll likely be guessing.

Comment: Thanks for respond :) Hey I have edited my question, please check and answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use html in the app you have to use react native webview. Check the source prop of the library

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/74872a1f02c43e425f19739b1b25f5fbe614ba1f/docs/Reference.md#source

If you want to use javascript functions from that file you can simply import it for ES6 or use require statement

Comment: I have edited my question, Can you please check and answer again, would be great :)

Comment: use injectedJavaScript prop to pass your javascript to the html and use source to provide static html. Hope it works!

Comment: Can you please give me any example of it, like to inject JS file inside `injectedJavaScript ` props ?

Comment: Follow this
https://medium.com/@idanlevi2/injecting-javascript-into-react-native-webview-521e4e55964b